# sum of $(\sqrt[n]{3} - 2)^{n}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Which convergence tests should I use here?
I know it diverges.

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\sqrt[n]{3} - 2)^{n}$

I've tried root and condensation tests but it led me nowhere.

Comment: $n$th term test for divergence?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Is $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[n]{3}-2)^n\stackrel{?}{=}0$

Comment: @samjoe I guess limit isn't zero

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but it's the right question to ask. (@samjoe: Double-check your limit.)

Comment: @Aaron Oh I understand it is oscillatory!

Comment: I didnt downvote, but have upvoted him now